# How can I change time column to include timezone in TimescaleDB?

Tags: timescaledb

How can I change column type from timestamp to timestamptz in TimescaleDB?

I used ingestion script [outflux](https://github.com/timescale/outflux) to get data from InfluxDB to TimescaleDB. This created tables that are using timestamp as their time column.

```sql
CREATE TABLE conditions (
    time        TIMESTAMP       NOT NULL,
    location    TEXT              NOT NULL,
    temperature DOUBLE PRECISION  NULL
);
```

I tried to convert it to timestamptz using standart [alter](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/hypertables/alter/) command

```sql
alter table conditions
alter column "time" type timestamptz using ("time"::timestamptz)
```

But that produced following error

```
ERROR:  check constraint "constraint_1007" of relation "_hyper_12_1007_chunk" is violated by some row
CONTEXT:  SQL statement " ALTER TABLE _timescaledb_internal._hyper_12_1007_chunk ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_1007 CHECK ( "time" >= TIMESTAMPTZ '2020-12-03 01:00:00+01' AND "time" < TIMESTAMPTZ '2020-12-10 01:00:00+01' ) "
PL/pgSQL function _timescaledb_internal.chunk_constraint_add_table_constraint(_timescaledb_catalog.chunk_constraint) line 42 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 23514
```

Answer (score -1):

You seem to think that `timestamptz` stores the timezone.
This is not true: None of the PostgreSQL types `timestamp` and `timestamptz` store the timezone.
They just treat the input differently: see this [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/1041641) about both types.

Once you understand this, you may find that you don't need to convert `timestamp` to `timestamptz`
When you still want to convert the types, then this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/134385/convert-postgres-timestamp-to-timestamptz) may help.